# Calculate Aggregate costs over any 3 month period in a year in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, recursion

I need to calculate if a member had 90 % of their total cost in the entire year over a 3 month period ( could be any 3 month period, not consecutive).

```
MemberID    MonthYearofDateofService  TotalCost 
 1              Jan2023                  100
 1              Feb2023                  100
 1              Mar2023                  1000
 1              Apr2023                  100
 1              May2023                  200
 1              Jun2023                  100
 1              Jul2023                  5000
 1              Aug2023                  300
 1              Sep2023                  330
 1              Oct2023                   50
 1              Nov2023                    0
 1              Dec2023                  100
```

I tried to use window function SUM, but I can only figure it out over consecutive months. I think there may be loops or a recursive function involved to figure this out.

Comment: Can you provide input and expected output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of window functions and subqueries in SQL.

```sql
WITH ThreeMonthPeriods AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT MonthYearofDateofService,NEWID() AS T
    FROM YourTableName
    ORDER BY NEWID()
    OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 3 ROWS ONLY
)
, RecursiveCTE AS (
    SELECT
        MemberID,
        MonthYearofDateofService,
        TotalCost,
        CAST(TotalCost AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS RunningTotal, -- Adjusted the data type
        1 AS MonthCount
    FROM
        YourTableName
    WHERE
        MonthYearofDateofService IN (SELECT MonthYearofDateofService FROM ThreeMonthPeriods)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        t.MemberID,
        t.MonthYearofDateofService,
        t.TotalCost,
        CAST(t.TotalCost + r.RunningTotal AS DECIMAL(10, 2)), -- Adjusted the data type
        r.MonthCount + 1
    FROM
        YourTableName t
    INNER JOIN
        RecursiveCTE r ON r.MemberID = t.MemberID
                       AND r.MonthYearofDateofService < t.MonthYearofDateofService
    WHERE
        r.MonthCount < 3
)
SELECT
    MemberID
FROM
    RecursiveCTE
WHERE
    RunningTotal >= 0.09 * (SELECT SUM(TotalCost) FROM YourTableName WHERE MemberID = RecursiveCTE.MemberID)
GROUP BY
    MemberID
HAVING
    COUNT(*) <= 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

Question is bit unclear but I am assuming that you are asking if out of all service money member earned, you need to mention if 90 percent of that money is earned in just 3 months. In this case you psude code will be something like

`Assumption, data is just there for single year. If more, group on year too`

```
with top_3_month_cost as
(
    select memberid, sum(TotalCost) as cost_for_top_3_months
    from (
    select memberid, TotalCost, row_number() over(group by memberid order by  TotalCost desc) as r from table
    )
    where r <=3
    group by memberid
),
total_cost as 
(
select memberid, sum(TotalCost) as TotalCost from table
group by memberid

)

select 
a.memberid, case when b.cost_for_top_3_months/a.TotalCost *100 >90 then True else False end as Is_more_than_90
from top_3_month_cost a
inner join total_cost b on a.memberid = b.memberid
```